# Узнать страницу на которой выведется только что выполненый INSERT

Tags: php, sql

На сайте с помощью `SELECT * ... LIMIT 0,10` реализован постраничный вывод строк с клиентами. При добавлении новой строки, вся таблица обновляется и новая строка подсвечивается с помощью css класса. 
Но получается так что новая строка может быть на другой странице (записи сортируются по колонке с именем). Как можно узнать на какой странице выведется новая строка что бы сразу показать пользователю эту страницу.

Сама пагинация реализована, интересует как определить страницу, на которой будет выводится новая строка, с учетом сортировки по имени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*) / 10) FROM client WHERE client.name <= ' . $name . ' ORDER BY client.name'
```

Где $name - имя нового клиента